# Random questions from different child from Firebase to Java andoird studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a quiz app using Firebase but I need to get 5 questions in total from different topics randomly and add them to `ArrayList<object>`. I already have generated 1 random question from only 1 topic (child) and I can not make this for the other 4 topics to have 5 questions from different topics
My Firebase database is here:
[image]

My code is:

```
final Query questionFromB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("B").orderByChild("questionID").equalTo(new Random().nextInt(15));
questionFromB.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot question : datasnapshot.getChildren()){
            if (questionCount < 1){
                questionView.setText(question.getValue(QuizQuestions.class).getQuestionText());
                answerText.setText(question.getValue(QuizQuestions.class).getAnswerText());

                arrayList.add(new QuizQuestions(question.getValue(QuizQuestions.class).getQuestionID(),question.getValue(QuizQuestions.class).getQuestionText(),question.getValue(QuizQuestions.class).getAnswerText()));
                datasnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                questionCount ++;
            }else{
                nextButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                nextActivityButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
                    textView.append(arrayList.get(i).getQuestionText());
                    textView.append(" \n ");
                    textView.append(" \n ");
                }

            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error, something was wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

(in the second activity i am just showing ArrayList contents in TextView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get results from multiple queries, then you should consider using [Query#get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()), which returns an object of type [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html). That being said, to merge 5 different Firebase Realtime Database requests locally, I recommend you to use [Tasks.whenAllSuccess()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)) method. You can achieve this, using the following lines of code:

```
Query questionFromA = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("A")
        .orderByChild("questionID")
        .equalTo(new Random()
        .nextInt(15));

Query questionFromB = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("B")
        .orderByChild("questionID")
        .equalTo(new Random()
        .nextInt(15));

//Create the other three queries.

Task aTask = questionFromA.get();
Task bTask = questionFromb.get();

//Create the other three Task objects.

Task combinedTask = Tasks.whenAllSuccess(aTask, bTask).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<Object> list) {
         //Do what you need to do with your list
    }
});
```

And pass all five Task objects to the `whenAllSuccess()` method. As you can see, when overriding the `onSuccess()` method the result is a list of objects. So you only have to map each object from the list into an object of type `QuizQuestions` and do what you need to do with them.

Comment: Can you show an example how to map them to that method ? I haven't done anything like that in java yet

Comment: It's a simple casting. I think you can get it from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51892766/android-firestore-convert-array-of-document-references-to-listpojo/51897261), right?

Comment: Hey there. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Sure, what information ?

Comment: I was asking if you need something else. Did my answer help?

Comment: can you send me direct message ? I need to ask something.